# Javascript bind "this" to event

Tags: javascript, mootools, jaml

Below is an error I am getting from binding "this" to a click event in javascript. The format of the js is Jaml/Mooml and may be unfamiliar to some but I assure you the syntax is proper. I have been binding "this" to many events in the same way and this is the first time I have seen this error so I am hoping some mootools, jaml or javascript expert will be able to derive a solution from the error and code below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get'
Mooml.engine.tags.div.Mooml.engine.tags.div.events.click:relay(a)
bubbleUpmootools-core-1.4.1.js:3948
delegation.addEvent.delegatormootools-core-1.4.1.js:4078
defn
```

here is the Jaml...

```
    'main': new Mooml.Template(null, function(data) {
        div({'class': 'lists container'},
            div({
                'class': 'sources',
                'events': {
                    'click:relay(a)': function(event) {
                        event.preventDefault();

                        new Resource({
                            'url': this.get('href'),
                            'method': 'FRIENDS',
                            'query' : {
                                'source': this.dataset.source
                            },

                            'onSuccess': function(response) {
                                console.log(response);
                                //this.renderTemplate('friends', response.mv, this);

                            }.bind(this),

                            'onFailure': this.onFailure

                        }).send();

                    }.bind(this)
                }
```

Comment: You say the syntax is correct but aren't you missing a closing `);`?

Comment: What `this` references in the main function? I mean, what `console.log(this)` gives you if you place it just before the 2nd `div()` call (line #3)?

Answer (score 4):

Add `var self = this`; before your code and then use `self` instead of `this` in the callback functions.

Also have a look at http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/ and http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/ to learn more about how `this` works.

Comment: thanks, that made me look at my resource call a little closer. I found the solution! Change this.get to event.target.get

Comment: @Adgezaza Can you share the solution (or where the problem was) with us?

Comment: can't answer my own question for another 7 hours. but just added the comment above.

Comment: @Adgezaza Using `event.target.get` is good and clever, however this does not tell us why your code was not working... Probably `this` was not referencing the `<div>` created in the `div()` call, so the missing reference is "propagated" using `.bind(this)`. That's the reason I ask you to check `console.log(this)` in the first lines of your code.

Comment: @lorenzo-s this was referring to the front end javascript controller which is the parent to the class where the snippet is taken from that I have built that contains a bunch of helper functions like the renderTemplate from the mooml class.

Comment: @Adgezaza Ok, so the problem was exactly there. Since `this` is not referencing to the element you want, `bind(this)` will simply bind what `this` refers to the inner functions. If you do not have a reference to created elements, you cannot use `bind()` to bind it to inner functions. Bye!